# How do I create a conditional format for my google sheet using only google scripting?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to learn how to use google scripts at my university but I don't quite fully get how to use conditional formatting? I am currently trying to do the following:

"A script to see who is eligible for scholarships for a free degree! Before you do so, go back to the sheet and create a new column on the spreadsheet with a header ‘eligibility’ Your script should then figure out if the student has above 80% attendance and be earning less than 30,000. Print in the cell in the relevant column to say either the student is eligible or not."

So I have 2 pieces of data that I need to conditional format but only using google script that is linked to a google sheet. I am not asking for the answer to be written out for me but I would like any help that anyone can give because I have no idea where to start?

If anyone could just show me specific rules or what codes I need for this, it'll be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Start by searching the official documentation. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of something you could do.  I use some data generators to generate random numbers.  Then I summed them for each row and then I normalized them to the row with the maximum sum. And the last loop sets the background colors based upon the colorA and the calculated idx.  Yellow is the max sum and the greens are the next highest range and the reds are all below 80 percent of the maxsum.

Here's the color:

```
function idWinners() {
  const colorA=['red','red','red','red','red','red','red','red','green','green','yellow'];
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet34');
  const shsr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let pA=[];
  let max=0;
  let maxro=0;
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    let sum=0;
    r.forEach((c,j)=>{
      sum+=c;
    });
    pA.push({total:sum,row:i+shsr})
    if(sum>max) {
      max=sum;
      maxro=i+shsr;
    }
  });
  pA.forEach((r,i)=>{
    r['nv']=r.total/max;//normalize all values to the max value
    r['idx']=Math.round(r.nv*10);//calculate background color index into color A
    r['color']=colorA[r.idx];
    sh.getRange(i+shsr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground(r.color);//set background color array for each row
  });
  const end="is near";
  }
```

So think about what kind of calculation that you need to perform on your data and how the background colors corellate to the background colors.  I did this code in about 20 minutes.  So once you're familiar with the scripting you can accomplish some pretty interesting things in just a short time.

Comment: thank you so much mate, I didn't think I would get a response so quickly! I will definitely read through this and figure it out!